# How to add innerhtml in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript in my application.

html code:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="last">
```

Typescript code:

```
let myContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('last');
myContainer.innerHTML = "";
```

I want to set the empty value for the last name field using typescript. 
I am using above code. But cannot able to add empty value using typescript.

I also tried by using below code:

```
document.getElementById('last').innerHTML = "";
```

How to assign empty value for the textbox using typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Html input elements have the value property, so it should be:

```
let myContainer = document.getElementById('last') as HTMLInputElement;
myContainer.value = "";
```

Notice that I also used `HTMLInputElement` instead of `HTMLElement` which does not have the `value` property.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use it like this

```
const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('personDetails') as HTMLElement
element.innerHTML = 'Hello World'
```

Works in Typescript 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use model value to bind to the element instead of using the id and inner html

Html code:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="last" ng-model="innerHtml">
```

Typescript code:

```
let innerHtml :string = "";
```

OR

if you want to use the inner Html by id then you have to use this

TypeScript uses '<>' to surround casts
Typescript code:

```
let element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("last");
element.value = "Text you want to give";
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a good practice, what we define in this way is not always the correct type.

```
let myContainer = document.getElementById('last') as HTMLInputElement;
myContainer.value = "";
```

or

```
const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('personDetails') as HTMLElement
element.innerHTML = 'Hello World'
```

if it is input use just HTMLInputElement